# Jupyter notebook stopped on [*]

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I was working on gremlin-python. My jupyter notebook was working fine before stopping my instance. When restarted it got stuck [*] here. Tried restarting/ reseting but nothing worked. Although I don't have enough permission so that I can check with SSH console.

Comment: You can add a detailed answer to your own question if you've got the solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

gremlin python uses tornado library which is also used by jupyter and I installed lower version of gremlin python which downgraded tornado library. I tried "jupyter notebook" command in the terminal. It gave me error and suggested to install tornado library with version >=6.1. Installed it and restarted jupyter notebook instance. It worked for me